# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Address' to 'String' in setter

Tags: c#, get, attributes, set

As in the title I try to make setter to `Adress` but I got this convert error .
Its code of my Worker class .

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace MAS_MP1
    {
        class Worker
        {
            string name, surname;
            protected string adress;
            int phoneNumber;
            string birthDate;

            Worker(String name, String surname, String adress, int phoneNumber, string birthDate)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.surname = surname;
                this.adress = adress;
                this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                this.birthDate = birthDate;

            }

           static List<Worker> list = new List<Worker>();

            public  static void add(Worker p)
            {
                list.Add(p);
            }
            public void setA(Adress a)
            {
                this.adress = a;
            }
            public static  void showExtension()


 {
            Console.WriteLine("Class Extesion");
            foreach (Worker p in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        override
        public string ToString()
        {
            return "Name " + name + " Surname " + surname;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Worker p = new Worker("Tom,","Smith","NewStreet 8 London",123456,"12-12-2012");
            Adress a = new Adress("NewStreet" , 9 , "London");
            add(p);
            showExtension();


        }
    }
}
```

And error was here :

```
public void setA(Adress a)
        {
            this.adress = a;
        }
```

I try to make a complex attribute so j make second class `Adress` only with constructor and toString override method. `Adress` got street , homeNumber and cityName attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How could this possibly work? You're trying to store an instance of `Adress` in a string...

```
protected string adress;

public void setA(Adress a)
{
    this.adress = a;
}
```

There's a couple fixes.

You could change the type of the field you're storing the value in:

```
protected Adress adress;
```

and change the constructor to accept an `Adress` as well:

```
Worker(String name, String surname, Adress adress, int phoneNumber, string birthDate)
```

Alternatively, modify your setter so you're storing a string:

```
public void setA(Adress a)
{
    this.adress = a.ToString();
}
```

Comment: One more question . Now when i create new object Worker , what i need to post under Adress ?

Comment: its constructor :  
Worker(String name, String surname, Adress adress, int phoneNumber, DateTime birthDate)

and here i create object 
Worker p = new Worker("Tom,","Smith",HERE,123456,"12-12-2012");

and my question is , what i need to post under "HERE"

Answer (score 0):

[Grant Winney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301857/grant-winney) is correct.

This code will not work because the type Adress is not the same as System.String. Although they derive from System.Object, you cannot implicitly convert this when performing the Set.

```
public void setA(Adress a)
            {
                this.adress = a;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an implicit conversion

```
 public class Address{
    //other code

    public static implicit operator Adress(string a)
    {
        return new Address(){Street = a};
    }
}
```

Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx